# Background EditText Alpha (transparência)

Tags: java, android, edittext

Gostaria de saber como faço para deixar o fundo do EditText com transparência, dessa forma:

[image: Campos]

Tentei das seguintes formas, mas sem sucesso:

edt.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/editText_alpha" />
</shape>
```

[image: Cor]

E tentei setar direto no `onCreate`:

```
mEmailView.setAlpha(0.7f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A única forma até o momento que funcionou, foi substituir o `shape` por um `gradient`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#9CE9E9E9"
        android:endColor="#9CE9E9E9"
        android:startColor="#9CE9E9E9" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu testei aqui, e a transparencia parece funcionar corretamente assim

```
<EditText      
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"//coloquei padding para criar espaçamento entre as extremidades e a letra
android:background="#6affffff" //Transaparencia pode ser adiciona aqui
android:hint="Texto da descrição" />
```

pode ser usado tbm `@android:color/transparent` para pegar valor 100% transaparente

Comment: Weslley assim só funciona direto no EditText. Eu precisava como um xml específico. Na verdade já até consegui. Vou postar.

Comment: Não entendi, qualquer XML que vc setar o background vai funcionar, até em um style se vc setar o background toda aplicação vai herdar

Comment: Pode ser ! Tentei puxar só `color`, o `background` não ! Estou deixando todo estilo para o final ! Rs... Posta na sua resposta fazendo por XML que confirmo e já confirmo a resposta. Valeu !